# On the limit $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \left( e^{\sqrt{x+2}} + e^{\sqrt{x-2}} - 2 e^{\sqrt{x}} \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate the limit

$$\ell = \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \left( e^{\sqrt{x+2}} + e^{\sqrt{x-2}} - 2 e^{\sqrt{x}} \right)$$

***without using differential calculus***.

I'm interested in evaluating the above limit using only pure limit theory without using MVT , Taylor etc. The limit is equal to $+\infty$ which is easy to extract using Taylor for example. I'm looking for  a way to evaluate it avoiding the *big guns*.

Comment: what is the point of asking calculus questions that we cannot answer with calculus...

Comment: I found the question in a school textbook before MVT or DLH. I'm really stuck. My solution is with MVT.

Comment: If my calculations (using Taylor expansions) are correct, it looks like the asymptotic behavior is $e^{\sqrt{x+2}} + e^{\sqrt{x-2}} - 2 e^{\sqrt{x}} \sim e^{\sqrt{x}} / x$.

Comment: Easy to solve with $\lim\limits_{t\to0}(e^t-1-t)/t^2$ known. (But why cut firewood with a jigsaw?..)

Comment: @metamorphy Care to share a more detailed hint?

Comment: Done in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(t)=(e^t-1-t)/t^2$; then $e^\sqrt{x+2}+e^\sqrt{x-2}-2e^\sqrt{x}=e^\sqrt{x}g(x)$, where
\begin{align*}
g(x)&=g_0(x)+g_-(x)+g_+(x),
\\g_\pm(x)&=h_\pm^2(x)f\big(h_\pm(x)\big),
\\h_\pm(x)&=\sqrt{x\pm 2}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{\pm 2}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x\pm 2}},
\\g_0(x)&=h_+(x)+h_-(x)
\\&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+2}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-2}}
\\&=\frac{2(\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{x+2})}{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+2})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-2})}
\\&=-\frac{8}{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+2})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-2})(\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x-2})}.
\end{align*}
Trivially $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}xh_\pm^2(x)=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}xg_0(x)=0$. **Now if we know that** $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}f(t)=1/2$, we obtain $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}xg(x)=1$, and finally $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}e^\sqrt{x}/x=+\infty$ implies that the given limit is $+\infty$.